# In Uncharted and Uncharted 2, how does Co-Op work?

Tags: uncharted, uncharted-series, uncharted-2

In Uncharted 3, there's a multiplayer option and Co-Op option which uses split-screen for two players. I'd like to know if there's such an option in the original Uncharted and Uncharted 2. How does Co-Op work in both games, is their a split screen, or is there no Co-Op at all?

Answer (score 3):

There is no co-op multiplayer in Uncharted and there is online only Co-Op in Uncharted 2 (10-15 minute sessions on average).

Comment: Are the servers still running on Uncharted 2?